# Access dataframe from inside a function from the outside

Tags: r, dataframe, function, global-variables

I wrote a function that randomly increases the **c%** percentage of data by **i%**. I need to do this on multiple dataframes. So the function does that, but I am unable to access the processed value from the outside.

```
library(tidyverse)

value <- iris[1:120,]

iris1 <- value[2:95,]

set.seed(42)

attackfunc <- function(day,dataattack,howmuchattack){

shuffled= day[sample(1:nrow(day)), ]

n = as.integer((dataattack/100)*nrow(day)) #select percentage of data to be changed

extracted <- shuffled[1:n, ]

extracted$changedload <- extracted[,1]*((howmuchattack/100)+1) #how much the data changes

pertubeddata<- shuffled %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = ifelse(row_number() <= n, extracted$changedload, Sepal.Length))

reshuffled <- pertubeddata[order(as.numeric(rownames(pertubeddata))),]

reshuffled}
```

I would like to access `reshuffled` from outside the function so that I can use that to do some more calculations.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `<<-` instead of `<-` to modify a variable of the parent scope. If the variable does not exist in the parent scope, it will be created. However, I think it would be best to `return(reshuffled)` and work with the returned object, to call another function inside your function or to simply append the function.

Comment: Can you just put the result into a dataframe? i.e. ```dat <-attackfunc()```

Comment: Thank you all....all of the ideas worked!!

Answer (score 1):

set reshuffled as an empty object before your formula, then in your formula change <- to <<- as per

```
reshuffled <<- pertubeddata[order(as.numeric(rownames(pertubeddata))),]
```

Hope this is useful